# type <class 'win32com.client.CDispatch>, how do I convert this into a readable format? This is for Automation of Microsoft Outlook Emails

Tags: python, winapi, automation, outlook

I want to create an automation program on Python where it reads through an inbox of unread emails and I want to be able to extract information from the subject line and put it on a Google Sheets.

However, I'm having trouble trying to append each email's subject line to a list to do some string manipulation.

```
import win32com.client as client

outlook = client.Dispatch('Outlook.Application')
namespace = outlook.GetNameSpace('MAPI')
account = namespace.Folders['test_email555@hotmail.com']
inbox = account.Folders['Inbox']

messages = inbox.Items
message = messages.GetLast()
emptyList = []


def test():
    Macq_Inst = [message for message in inbox.Items if message.Unread == True]

    for msg in Macq_Inst:
        # emptyList.append(msg) 
        # print(emptyList)
        print(type(msg))


    for item in Macq_Inst:
        date = item.SentOn.strftime("%m/%d/%Y, %H:%M:%S")
        print(date)

test()
```

I get the following output:

```
OutlookAutomation.py::test PASSED                                        [100%][<COMObject <unknown>>, <COMObject <unknown>>, <COMObject <unknown>>, <COMObject <unknown>>]
[<COMObject <unknown>>, <COMObject <unknown>>, <COMObject <unknown>>, <COMObject <unknown>>, <COMObject <unknown>>]
[<COMObject <unknown>>, <COMObject <unknown>>, <COMObject <unknown>>, <COMObject <unknown>>, <COMObject <unknown>>, <COMObject <unknown>>]
10/25/2021, 22:26:16
10/25/2021, 22:26:36
10/25/2021, 22:26:48
```

If I print out the msg variable, I get the subject line of my 3 emails:

```
OutlookAutomation.py::test PASSED                                        [100%]FW: Instructions – ExampleName1, ID-123345
FW: Instructions – ExampleName2, ID-123453
FW: Instructions – ExampleName3, ID-135241
10/25/2021, 22:26:16
10/25/2021, 22:26:36
10/25/2021, 22:26:48
```

My msg variable returns the following type:

```
OutlookAutomation.py::test PASSED                                        [100%]<class 'win32com.client.CDispatch'>
<class 'win32com.client.CDispatch'>
<class 'win32com.client.CDispatch'>
10/25/2021, 22:26:16
10/25/2021, 22:26:36
10/25/2021, 22:26:48
```

Is there a way that I can read this <class 'win32com.client.CDispatch'> and convert this into a string or something so that I can append into an empty list?

If not possible, would there be another way of doing this?

Comment: You get an error because `append` is a function.  Instead of subscripting it with brackets `[]`, you need to call it: `emptyList.append(msg)` .

Comment: Hello, Thanks for pointing that out. I've now edited the question as I am still unable to convert this class object.

Answer (score 0):

try `str(msg)`

From what I understand with python the reason why you are getting the string message is because the is probable a **str** method in the CDispatch class that returns the subject of the mail object. By default print calls the **str** method of the class.

so if you call the `__str__` method yourself. You should be golden

Comment: Hey W. Mayo, thanks for answering my questions. I was able to solve this by encoding the text into ascii to convert it into text via:

`y = str(msg.Subject.encode('ascii', 'ignore'))`